# Convert object with Avro fields to json

Tags: java, json, avro

I have the following code to convert an object to Json:

```
public static Function<Object, Object> WRITE_JSON = (Object val) -> {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(val);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
        return "";
    }         
}
```

This works fine for most cases, but f.e I have an Avro class named `AvroData`, and a class that saves it:

```
class SomeData {
    private AvroData avroData;
    // more fields, getter/setter boilerplate, etc...
}
```

When I try to serialise the object to `Json`, this fails when trying to serialize the `Avro` field.
In reality, I have a bit more data, like `Set`s and `Map`s that contain `Avro` record values, but I think the point stands.

How do you manage to serialise a avro to json, but specifically when it's part of a Non-avro object?

Answer (score -1):

To convert your `Object val` in JSON with Jackson:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(val);
```

Comment: How does this handle the `avro` records?

Comment: Did you find an answer?